# How can play multiple audios one by one?

Tags: flutter, audio, dart

I have a lot of audios to put it on my flutter application. I stored them as zip file in firebase then downloaded it on documents directory then unzipped. But how can I play these audios as a playlist? There's a plugin available assets_audio_player but it only plays audios from assets but not from other directory. Other plugins only play or loop one audio but not have playlist function. What can I do? or how can I add audio dynamically to my flutter assets folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by yourself - when some track is finished, play the next one from the list.

Or you can try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_plugin_playlist